# How can I autoreload ChoiceBox when new device was connected?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am a new in JavaFX and I am trying to update ChoiceBox when new device like flash card was connected. I do it using ScheduleService which has period 500ms. After each 500ms I get a list of removable devices and add them to ObservableList:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    ScheduledService<List<String>> service = getListOfDevices();
    service.setPeriod(Duration.millis(500));
    service.start();
    service.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
        Platform.runLater(() -> flashCardObservableList.setAll(service.getLastValue()));

    });

    nckCardList.setItems(flashCardObservableList);
}

private ScheduledService<List<String>> getListOfDevices() {
    return new ScheduledService<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        protected Task<List<String>> createTask() {
            return new Task<List<String>>() {
                @Override
                protected List<String> call() throws Exception {
                    String result = usb.GetDriveInfo();
                    List<FlashCard.DriveInfo> drives;
                    List<String> diskLetters = new ArrayList<>();
                    if (result.isEmpty() || result == null) return diskLetters;
                    drives = FlashCard.deserialize(result);
                    for (FlashCard.DriveInfo d : drives) {
                        diskLetters.add(d.getFlashName());
                    }
                    return diskLetters;
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

For getting list of devices I am using DLL and in this DLL I use method DriveInfo.GetDrives(). But every 500ms my choiceBox is updating and I cannot pick anything. I want it to look like in the program "Rufus" in the field - "Device".
What is the best way to do so?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are resetting the list of devices every half second. Why don't you check whether the returned list of devices is different to the `ObservableList` and only update the `ObservableList` when a change occurs?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Abra. Yes, you understood correctly. I thought about it but, because of not having experience I do not know which decision will be precise

Comment: [mcve] please .. you can mock the device lookup (if it's working with the mock, there might be something wrong in the device access)